# How to handle null in Linq Expression

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda, repository-pattern

Net core application. I have generic repository pattern implemented. I am doing some kind of filter functionalities as below.

```
 var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SiteAssessmentRequest), "x");
 Expression<Func<SiteAssessmentRequest, bool>> query;
 if(request.role == "Admin")
 {
 query = null;
 }
 else
 {
   query = x => x.CreatedBy == request.Userid || x.AssignedTo == request.Userid;
 }
 Expression body = Expression.Invoke(query, param);
 if (request.Client != null && request.Client.Length != 0)
            {
                Expression<Func<SiteAssessmentRequest, bool>> internalQuery = x => request.Client.Contains(x.Client);
                body = Expression.AndAlso(Expression.Invoke(query, param), Expression.Invoke(internalQuery, param));
            }
  if (request.CountryId != null && request.CountryId.Length != 0)
            {
                Expression<Func<SiteAssessmentRequest, bool>> internalQuery = x => request.CountryId.Contains(x.CountryId);
                body = Expression.AndAlso(Expression.Invoke(query, param), Expression.Invoke(internalQuery, param));
            }
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<SiteAssessmentRequest, bool>>(body, param);
 var siteAssessmentRequest = await _siteAssessmentRequestRepository.GetAsync(lambda, x => x.OrderByDescending(x => x.Status == Status.New.ToString()).ThenByDescending(x => x.Status == GetEnumDescription(Status.InProgress)).ThenByDescending(x => x.Status == Status.Closed.ToString()).ThenByDescending(x => x.StartDate), x => x.Country).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

In the above code whenever Admin Logs in I do not want to filter. In case of Admin when I assign null to query following exception it throws at below line

```
Expression body = Expression.Invoke(query, param);
```

> Parameter: expression is required, it cannot be empty

Can someone help me to fix this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I think your problem is in

```
if(request.role == "Admin"){ query = null; }
else{
   query = x => x.CreatedBy == request.Userid || x.AssignedTo == request.Userid;
}
```

this Section. And you do not want to filter the query when the request is coming from the Admin. So, I think you can try this

```
if(request.role == "Admin")
{ 
   query = x => x.CreatedBy > 0;
}

//If CreatedBy is String Type
if(request.role == "Admin")
{ 
   query = x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.CreatedBy) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.CreatedBy);
}
```

Because, CreatedBy should be available for every single items.

**Note:** Please try that and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Hi It worked for me but createdby was string so I was unable to give > 0 so what i did is i gave   query = x => x.SiteAssessmentRequestId > 0;

Comment: I have edited my answer for you . You can try `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.CreatedBy) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.CreatedBy)` if you want to use CreatedBy Property. :)